# AJAX Form not submitting unless if page is reloaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, form-submit

Good day guys...i need a little help help with a page containing a form being submitted with jquery...the form works fine however it only works if the browser is refreshed. When the page is opened through a link the form submit does not respond at all until you refresh the browser! In fact none of the scripts on the page respond including the validation script...until the browser is refreshed...i need help solving this issue

register.html looks like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="register" data-theme="b">

    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    
            <div class="content-block-login">
                            <div class="form_logo">Create an Account</div>
                            <div id="error_message"></div>
                            <div class="loginform">
                                <form class="register-form" id="RegisterForm">
                                
                                <input type="text" name="Username" id="reg-username" class="form_input required" placeholder="username" data-role="none" />
                                
                                <input type="text" name="Email" id="reg-email" value="" class="form_input required" placeholder="email" data-role="none" />
                                <input type="password" name="Password" id="reg-password" value="" class="form_input required" placeholder="password" data-role="none" />
                                <input type="password" name="Password" id="reg-repeat-password" value="" class="form_input required" placeholder="confirm password" data-role="none" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="device_fingerprint" id="dfp" value="" />
                                <button type="submit" id="btn-register" class="form_submit" >Register</button>
                                </form>
                             
                            </div>
       
            </div>

    </div>


</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/register.js"></script>

<script>
$( "#RegisterForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
   event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This page works fine the form validation and submission all work fine, however if this page is open through a link none of the script seem to respond. when you click #btc-register the page simply reloads with nothing else happening...
Any suggestions will be appreciated

below is register.js

```
enter  $(document).ready(function () {
//button register click
$("#btn-register").click(function () {

  //  alert("yes me");
    if(register.validateRegistration() === true) {
        //validation passed
        var regMail     = $("#reg-email").val(),
            regUser     = $("#reg-username").val(),
            regPass     = $("#reg-password").val(),
            regPassConf = $("#reg-repeat-password").val(),
            devFinger   = $("#dfp").val();

        var data = { 
            userData: {
                email           : regMail,
                username        : regUser,
                password        : regPass,
                confirm_password: regPassConf,
                dfp             : devFinger

            },
            fieldId: {
                email           : "reg-email",
                username        : "reg-username",
                password        : "reg-password",
                confirm_password: "reg-repeat-password",
                dfp             : "dfp"

            }
        };

        //send data to server
        register.registerUser(data);

    }                        
});
```

});
var register = {};

register.registerUser = function (data) {

```
var btn = $("#btn-register");
asengine.loadingButton(btn, "Validating...");

$.ajax({
    url: "http://mywebsite/api/Ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        action  : "registerUser",
        user    : data
    },
    success: function (result) {

        asengine.removeLoadingButton(btn);

        console.log(result);

        var rstatus = result.status;
        var rmsg = result.msg;

        if(rstatus === "error") {
            //error
            var rerrors = result.errors[0].msg;
            jQuery("#btn-register").html("Registration Failed!!");

        }
        else {
            //display success message
            $("#error_message").addClass("successflash");
            $("#error_message").html("<p>" + rmsg + "</p>");
            setTimeout($("#btn-register").html("Success!"),7000);

        }
    }
});
```

};

register.validateRegistration = function () {
    var valid = true;

```
asengine.removeErrorMessages();


//check if all fields are filled
$(".register-form").find("input").each(function () {
    var el = $(this);

    if($.trim(el.val()) === "") {
        var errorMsg = "All fields are required!!!";
        asengine.displayErrorMessage(el,errorMsg);
        valid = false;
    }
});

//get email, password and confirm password for further validation
var regMail     = $("#reg-email"),
    regPass     = $("#reg-password"),
    regPassConf = $("#reg-repeat-password");

//check if email is valid
if(!asengine.validateEmail(regMail.val()) && regMail.val() != "") {
    valid = false;
    asengine.displayErrorMessage(regMail,"You have entered an Invalid Email Address!!!");
}

//check if password and confirm password fields are equal
if(regPass.val() !== regPassConf.val() && regPass.val() != "" && regPassConf.val() != "") {
    valid = false;
    asengine.displayErrorMessage(regPassConf, "Your passwords do NOT match!!!");
}

return valid;
```

}; 
 here

Comment: Ehm... Your #RegisterForm submit script does nothing but stop the form submitting. It doesn't do or send any information.
Is the AJAX/$.post code in either "index.js" or "register.js"?

Comment: because it works in one scenario and not another, you would need to provide examples of those.  I echo @FelixMichaelCervin in that there are missing elements from the provided sample that prevent verification of your problem.

Comment: Sorry, but that made no sense to me. There is no AJAX code to troubleshoot in the snippet you've provided. Again; you are **not** displaying **any** AJAX-code.

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick reply...the ajax code is run in register.js and the validation is done in index.js. I did not post those two files because the problem does not lie in the ajax codes but rather in the html file...when you access the html file directly such http://mywebsite/register.html the form does not submit...it looks like the #btn-register does not trigger anything but once you reload the browser i.e (F12) then everything works fine...

Comment: You seem to complicate a rather simple thing. Instead of doing it like this, with a ton of unecessary code, have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ .